# How to hide an element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Am having the following code..

```
<img src="" id="image1" >
<img src="www" id="image1" >

<img src="" id="image2" >
<img src="www" id="image2" >

<div id="imagesrc"></div>
```

How can I hide a `div` with an `id` `(#imagesrc)` when `#image1` have `src=""`, and show my `div` `(#imagesrc`) when `#image1` have `src !=""`?

Comment: Your question is unclear because you have multiple elements with the same ID. The div `#imagesrc` cannot be shown and hidden at the same time. Or are these just examples, and there is only one element with the same ID and you just duplicated it to demonstrate that the element can have different values for `src`?

Comment: FWIW, if it is like I said, the shortest JS solution would be `$('#imagesrc').toggle($('#image1[src!='']').length > 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#image1").attr("src") == "") {
            $("#imagesrc").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#imagesrc").show();
        }
    });
```

**Update**

```
$("#image1").change(function () {
var imgControlName = "#imagesrc";

readURL(this, imgControlName);
 if (jQuery("#preview").attr("src") == "") {
    jQuery("#remove").hide();
} else {
    jQuery("#remove").show();

}
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/7/)

Comment: Not work. When src =="" hidden my id, but when uploand my image and appear src data, not show my id.

Comment: how do you upload the image?

Comment: Here is my code. http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/5/. I want show remove button when src != "", else not show.

Comment: Button should disappear if I delete the picture.

Answer (score 2):

CSS is clean, is JavaScript-free, and responds to changes automatically.

Of course, it assumes that your markup really looks like that.

```css
#image1[src=""] ~ #imagesrc {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function(){ //ready function 
    $('#imagesrc').show(); //show the imagesrc div.you can avoid this, if imagesrc div is already shown
    if($('#image1').attr('src')==""){ //check for condition
        $('#imagesrc').hide(); //if true hide it
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

//include jquery.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 if($('#image1').attr('src')==""){
  $('#imagesrc').hide(); //you can also give $('#imagesrc').css('display','none');
 }
});
</script>
```

Also please do not place same "id" to more than 1 element. Instead, use a class.

I hope you get an idea...

Comment: Not work. When src =="" hidden my id, but when uploand my image and appear src data, not show my id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this full code

you can use `attr` to call any html element  `attribute` value or to set `attribute` value

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<img src="" id="image1" >
<img src="www" id="image1" >

<img src="" id="image2" >
<img src="www" id="image2" >

<div id="imagesrc"></div>


<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

  if ($("#image1").attr("src") == "")
  {
      $("#imagesrc").hide();
   }
   else
   {
      $("#imagesrc").show();
   }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not work. When src =="" hidden my id, but when uploand my image and appear src data, not show my id.

Comment: what you mean of upload my image , are you using another code please post it here you need to mix your codes for final result

Comment: Here is my code. http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/5/. I want show remove button when src != "", else not show.

Answer (score 0):

Try any one of the below approach.

```
 if($("#image1").attr('src') != ''){
       $('#imagesrc').hide();
    }else{
       $('#imagesrc').show();
    }
```

or

```
$('#imagesrc').toggle($("#image1").attr('src') != '');
```

Comment: Not work. When src =="" hidden my id, but when uploand my image and appear src data, not show my id.

Comment: After uploading the image you should call the same code again to make the image visible

Comment: Here is my code. http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/5/. I want show remove button when src != "", else not show.

Comment: Upload (Add) a invalid file. if the image src is empty show remove button otherwise don't show. Hope this is what, you are trying to achieve.